# Can I force Firefox to never leak referrers?

Tags: firefox, privacy, http-referrer

From https://webbkoll.dataskydd.net/en/

> Thanks to a fairly recent development, [Referrer Policy](https://w3c.github.io/webappsec-referrer-policy/), it's finally possible for websites to tell browsers to not leak referrers. It lets you specify a policy that's applied to all links clicked, as well as all other requests generated by the page (images, JS, etc.).

Is it possible for me to configure Firefox to never leak referrers, rather than relying each and every website to implement Referrer Policy?

Answer (score 2):

Firefox has several configuration options to control how it sends referrer headers.

Enter `about:config` in the address bar. In the search field, type `referer` (note that referrer is spelled incorrectly). One of the configuration options is network.http.sendRefererHeader. Setting this option to not send referrer headers may break the functionality of some web sites.

network.http.sendRefererHeader:

- controls whether or not to send a referrer regardless of origin
     values:

  - 0 = never send the header
  - 1 = send the header only when clicking on links and similar elements
  - 2 = (default) send on all requests (e.g. images, links, etc.)

Here's a list of Firefox [Security/Referrer](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Security/Referrer) configuration options.